# Selecting a JLabel by knowing its Name

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

If I have many JLabels on the screen and I know their names how would I go about selecting finding them?

For example I know that I previously (dynamically) created a new JLabel with the name 2340. Is there something like

```
JLabel image = findJlabel ("2340");
```

In order to select the JLabel component?

Thanks, 
Neco

EDIT: Just want to show how I am creating these JLabels

```
// Initially creates all the imagelabels
    public static void createImageLabels (){
        int xcord, ycord;
        JLabel image;
        String imageLabelName; 

        xcord = 0;
        ycord = yOffset;
        for (int row = 0 ; row < map.length; row++) {
            xcord = 0;
            for (int  col = 0 ; col < map[0].length; col++) {
                imageLabelName = Integer.toString(row);
                imageLabelName += Integer.toString(col);
                image = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(space));
                image.setName(imageLabelName);      
                image.setLocation(xcord, ycord);
                image.setSize(24, 24);
                imagePanel.add(image);  
                System.out.println ("Created a Jlabel Named "+imageLabelName);
                xcord += 24;
            }
            ycord += 24;
        }
    }
```

I create a tile of imageIcons on the screen and then later on if I want to change the image displayed by them I want to select it and change it.

Comment: What do you mean by "you know its name" and "dynamically created"? If you created it, surely you can have your program keep track of it without having to go through everything to find it later on?

Comment: The Jlabel in question is a ImageIcon and I'm just trying to change the image that it's currently displaying later on in the program.

Comment: Simpler way to do that would be to keep reference of it in a `HashMap<String,JLabel> jlabelMap;` and use this map to figure out which JLabel you have to modify.

Comment: Just declare the JLabel as a global variable in the class

Comment: 1) *"`findJlabel ("2340");`"* You mean there is a `2339`, `2338` etc.?  This entire question screams `JList` or `JTable` to me.  What are you actually trying to achieve through all this?  What application *feature* does it provide? 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 3):

Well, assuming you have different names for all labels, i would recommend you using HashMaps.

```
HashMap<String, JLabel> labels = new HashMap<String,JLabel>();
```

Inside you "for" sicle, use:

```
labels.put("1233", new JLabel(new ImageIcon(space)));
```

To use your the label you want, use:

```
labels.get("1233");
```

For more information, check:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

Comment: (Java 1.4 is a little out of date ... might be nice to link to a more update doc reference - IMHO)

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to find the component with the concept of the current container it easy, if you want to search child or parent containers, it becomes little more complicated...

```
public JLabel findLabelByName(Container parent, String name) {
    JLabel found = null;
    if (name != null) {
        for (Component child : parent.getComponents()) {
            if (child instanceof JLabel) {
                JLabel label = (JLabel)child;
                if (name.equals(label.getName()) {
                    found = label;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return found;
}
```

Now, if you want to search up or down the container hierarchy, you would need to perform a recursive call to this method, passing in the new parent, but I'm sure you can figure that out, don't want to rob you of all the fun ;)

Comment: I don't mind the `Map` technique, my only issue is it's potential memory leak, at least this way when labels are added and removed, you can always find them - not as fast as the `Map` though...

Comment: +1 true, I normally  just make sure to remove the label after removing it from container but very true indeed.

Answer (score 0):

> In order to select the JLabel component?

how are you 'selecting' the label?

if it's via the mouse, just add a mouseListener and use getSource()